# How can I use the variable outside localSocket?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, svelte

I have a Svelte based project. I'm using Socket.io on the backend. I was able to pull a data from the backend to the client side as a localsocket. Console log gives correct results. But I can only use this variable in localSocket. How can I export it? I want to use in div as {Player1} and {Player2}.

```
const localSocket = get(socket);
localSocket.on('RoundPlayers', (describingPlayer, gozetciPlayer) => {
        const Player1 = describingPlayer.nickname;
        const Player2 = gozetciPlayer.nickname;
        console.log(Player1 + " " + Player2);

    });
```

When I try to use it in the following way, I get the error {Player1}, {Player2} is not defined. But console.log is work

```
<script lang="ts">
...
const localSocket = get(socket);
    localSocket.on('RoundPlayers', (describingPlayer, gozetciPlayer) => {
            const Player1 = describingPlayer.nickname;
            const Player2 = gozetciPlayer.nickname;
            console.log(Player1 + " " + Player2);
    
        });
</script>
<div>Next Players: {Player1} and {Player2}</div>
```

I hope I was able to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, inner scopes see variables from outer scopes.

So, simply:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    ...
    let Player1
    let Player2

    const localSocket = get(socket);

    localSocket.on('RoundPlayers', (describingPlayer, gozetciPlayer) => {
        Player1 = describingPlayer.nickname;
        Player2 = gozetciPlayer.nickname;
        console.log(Player1 + " " + Player2);
    });
</script>

<div>Next Players: {Player1} and {Player2}</div>
```

Furthermore, Svelte tracks changes to root scope `let` variables when they are reassigned (in Svelte components only, of course). So with this code, your markup will get updated each time your receive new values.